# Arrange numbers to 3 different math operations

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory, alphametic

Replace letters with numbers 1 to 9,
so the 3 operations below are equals.
Each letter represents one unique number.

> $$\frac{ab}{c} = de \times f = gh - i$$

Comment: `ab = a x b`? or if they are numbers `a=1, b=2`, `ab = 12`? same for `de` and `gh`

Comment: @lois6b I assume the latter, since the multiplication is indicated by a '*'

Comment: @Wu33o I thought that too, but dont like to assume

Comment: @lois6b :  a = 1, b = 2, ab = 12

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think

> $\frac{78}2=39\times1=45-6$

works fine

How I reached the result:

> I assumed $f=1$ and $c=2$. As a conclusion, the value of the division (and thus all the expressions) has to be less than $50$, so $d$ is either $3$ or $4$, and $g=d+1$. After a few trials I found the solution above.